# Unable to change hostname in Ubuntu 18.04 server on Virtualbox

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualbox

What I’ve tried:

- `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ubuntu-1`
- `echo ‘ubuntu-1’ > /etc/hostname`

Sadly, whenever I `reboot` the hostname changes back to what it was originally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be solved by changing **preserve_hostname** to **true** in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

To reiterate:

1. Set **preserve_hostname true** in */etc/cloud/cloud.cfg*
2. Update hostname`sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ubuntu-1`
3. `reboot`

Comment: Thanks, this was the only thing that worked for me. I had been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: This is quite informative. I found that ubuntu stored hostname in /var/lib/cloud and did a bunch of other stuff. One other way was to disable cloud-init `systemctl disable cloud-init`

Comment: Thanks, if this works you may have saved my life

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the GUI instead of the CLI:
Go to Settings > About > Device Name > Rename Device.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change name , because its getting displayed as command prompt in terminal,
then you can replace "\h" in PS1 with "desired host name" in ~/.bashrc.

Like in ~/.bashrc put this line at end of file :

export PS2="continue-> ";

export PS1="\u@3050:~$ ";